In R: Manually change data and get corresponding R code
In R Studio (or somewhere else), is there the possibility to manually change entries in a data frame and then get the corresponding code of the changing steps for documentation?
I know the function edit which nicely opens a window for editing. But it does not generate the corresponding code.
The reason is: I have a rather large data set where I need a bunch of manual edits. It would be great, if I could document them directly in the code rather than change the data in Excel or wherever. But it's a quite much work to write it down and I thought, there must be a functionality that generates this code automatically.

There should be a file .Rhistory in your working directory recording the instructions you ran to change the data. Is this what you are looking for?

I'm not entirely sure of the question you are asking. However, the transmute() function in the dplyr package works wonders. Here is a brief description: dplyr package

This package may also prove to be helpful: tidyverse

The R History does only show the edit command. I would like to see the complete R code of the changings, entry per entry. I'm happy if it's tidyverse, base R would be fine too.

"I know the function edit which nicely opens a window for editing." You should never use that if you care about reproducibility (which you seem to do).

I added a reason to my question. And @Roland: Yeah, that's exactly my thoughts. But it's laborious to write down a reproducible code in my case.

Perhaps logging of sorts

Run waldo::compare(old, new) and you're sorted.

I agree quite strongly with Roland's comment, but if this is something you have to do, then documenting those changes is vital.  You could do this by comparing the edited data to the original data and then producing the code that would get you to the new data from the original.  Here's an example with the mtcars data.  First, make sure you've got an observation number in the data, I've called it obs below.  You'll need to modify the code if you call it something else.  In the data, I created some character strings and factors to show how it would work with different kinds of variables.
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number(), 
         am = factor(mtcars$am, levels=c(0,1), labels = c("Auto", "Man")), 
         model = rownames(mtcars), .before="mpg")
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
orig <- mtcars

I edited the data and saved it as new.  I document the changes I made in the code chunk.
new <- edit(mtcars)

# changed model for obs 1 to "Mazda RX4 Cpe"
# changed mpg for obs 20 to 20
# changed cyl for obs 17 to 4
# changed hp for obs 3 to 150
# changed AM for obs 4 to "Man"
# changed AM for obs 2 to "Auto"

Finally, you could loop through the variable names, identify where the differences are in each variable and make the code that assigns the different value to the appropriate observation in the original dataset. Once you've got all the recodes, you could write them out to a separate file with something like cat(recodes, file="recodes.r", sep="\n")
recodes <- NULL
nms <- names(mtcars)
for(n in nms){
  inds <- which(orig[[n]] != new[[n]])
  if(length(inds) > 0){
    if(inherits(orig[[n]], "factor") | inherits(orig[[n]], "character")){
      recodes <- c(recodes, sapply(inds, \(i)paste0("orig$", n, "[",i,"] <- '", new[[n]][i], "'")))
    }else{
      recodes <- c(recodes, sapply(inds, \(i)paste0("orig$", n, "[",i,"] <- ", new[[n]][i])))
    }
  }
}
recodes
#> [1] "orig$model[1] <- 'Mazda RX4 Cpe'" "orig$mpg[20] <- 20"              
#> [3] "orig$cyl[17] <- 4"                "orig$hp[3] <- 150"               
#> [5] "orig$am[2] <- 'Auto'"             "orig$am[4] <- 'Man'"

Created on 2024-12-18 with reprex v2.1.0

I have done something different which sort of ends up the same:  I  finish off a function with  return(list(result = result_data,  x_in = x_in,  y_in = y_in))  so that a single object contains all the input values used.    I am strongly biased against using a script/macro when a function can be used instead.

@CarlWitthoft that sounds like perfectly reasonable preference to me.  Just from what you've written, I'm not exactly sure how it would work, but  it sounds like a good idea.

This looks pretty similar to the output you'd get from running waldo::compare(orig, new).

I think if you wanted to visualize  what the differences are, the waldo approach is superior.  If you want a script so that you could get from the original data to the new data without editing again, the waldo output would need to be modified significantly, unless I'm missing something.  It also would be more cumbersome on really large data.
